# How to correctly use a left join on datetime fields

Tags: t-sql

We are looking for hourly sales data for all products that had any sales in the last 4 months (our system writes a record every hour with the total number of sales for each product, but only for products with sales).  I created a view that computes every hour for the past 4 months and that works correctly.  When I do a left join though, it's acting like a right join in that it's only returning records where there were sales for that hour.  When there are no sales, there is no zero record returned.  What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) as total, product_name, vw.dates 
FROM vwGetHours4Months vw 
LEFT JOIN Product_Sales ps ON vw.Dates=ps.sales_hour
GROUP BY product_name,vw.dates
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: Is this the full query or just part of it? This should work... Is `Product_Sales` a `BASE TABLE`? Is the `product_name` really a part of `Product_Sales`? Might be there is just kind of a `product_ID` and an `INNER JOIN` to a `product` table? Could you please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are grouping by product_name and since that would be null for hours when there is no sale it is omitted from the result.

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) as total, product_name, vw.dates 
FROM vwGetHours4Months vw 
LEFT JOIN Product_Sales ps ON vw.Dates=ps.sales_hour
GROUP BY isnull(product_name,''),vw.dates
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```